# How to get a subheader and form inline?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I get a header and a form inline?

```
<h2 class="sub-header">Name</h2>
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="input" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" title="Save">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    </button>
<form>
```

I want the form on the right side and the sub-header on the left side, so I tried to add `pull-right` to the form-class, but it still does not work, the form is always under my sub-header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the form_inline a float right in CSS.

```
.form_inline {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -XXpx;
}
```

The margin-top is to setup the height of the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
h2 , .form-inline , .form-group{
    display:inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JvfqB/

Something like this?

Edit:
Just cleared it up a little (but refer to the original jsfiddle):

http://jsfiddle.net/JvfqB/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the css float

```
.Anyclass{
float:right;
}
```

Another method is the css display element

```
.AnyClass{
 display:inline
 }
```